# How to find Winding number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $r:[0, 2\pi]\to\Bbb C$ be the circle given by $r(t)=1+2e^{2it}$, what is the winding number of $r(t)$ around $z=2$?

I struck at :

If $r(t)=1+2e^{it}$ then we can write as $|z-1|=2$, but
How can write $r(t)=1+2e^{2it}$,  in the circle form?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $z=2$ is inside the circle, and the path goes twice around that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can still write this as the circle described by $|z-1|=2$, the function just goes around the circle twice, since the exponent over $i$ ranges from $0$ to $4\pi$, which is twice $2\pi$